# Winforms, can I use a text box here instead of a combobox? (dropdown list with over 15k options)

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, combobox, textbox

For the last few weeks I've been building a product demo for work which includes a winform to enter new customer enquiry information. One of the form elements is a text box which, for the sake of ease, I haven't imposed any validation on so far. However, I now need to make it so that the user can only enter a valid location from an sql database table (containing around 15k streets).

I'm still quite new to C# programming. My first thought was that I should change my text box to a combobox but I seem to remember that when you click on a combobox all the options in the list appear before you've typed anything. Since our computers are slow and there's so many options, I don't really want to flood the screen so I was wondering if there was a way I could continue using my text box and onkeypress (probably the tab key) a dialogue pops up with all the closest matches from the list, prompting the user to select a valid option?

If not, is there a way to stop my combobox from showing the option list until prompted?

Comment: hi check out this link https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/autocomplete-textbox-in-windows-form-application-using-sql-server1

Comment: I'd probably go for a TextBox with [validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/input-keyboard/validation?view=netdesktop-5.0) and [Auto-Complete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textbox.autocompletesource?view=net-5.0).

Comment: Echo Fildor's comment, and make the autocomplete source dynamic; don't put 15k items in it, perform a db search after the user types 3 chars and put th more limited number of rows in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not think a combobox is not well suited for that many items.

The way I have approach this is to use a separate list view to show matches. You could probably put matches in a drop-down style borderless window, but I find that more complex and may be difficult to make the interaction work well.
I would just have the streets in a separate list view control and apply a filter to that.

Make sure the view is resizable, I find it very frustrating when working with old window controls where the list is tiny due to it being written for 640x480 screens, and does not allow resizeing.

Keep performance in mind, when searching with each key-press you might want to fetch all records and do the search in memory rather than making a sql query for each key.